# TypeError: expected dynamic type 'double' but had type 'string'

Tags: react-native

I'm running into this error when trying to use `datePickerAndroid` and setting the state afterwards.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuYfx.png)

I feel like the problem may be from the initial state being a `new Date()` but not 100% sure.

```
  _isAndroid = async () => {
    let {action, year, month, day} = await DatePickerAndroid.open({
      date: this.props.startDate,
    });

    if (action === DatePickerAndroid.dismissedAction) {
      this.props.closeModal()
    } else {
      const date = year + "-" + month + "-" + day
      this.props.onDateChange(date)
    }
  }

  Prop Function:

  onDateChange = (newDate) => {
    this.setState({currentDate: newDate}) // <- This one is breaking
    let dates = this.state.dates;
    let index = this.state.currentIndex;

    if (this.state.currentKey === "start") {
      dates[index].start = newDate
    } else {
      dates[index].end = newDate
    }

    this.setState({dates: dates});
  }
```

I've narrowed it down to the first `setState`, and I've tried making the initial state a string as well as setting the state to a simple string but still getting the error.

Comment: Does it expect milliseconds: `newDate.getTime()`?

Comment: Which line of code is that?

Comment: `this.setState({currentDate: newDate})`

Comment: I don't think so, it works normally so long as I don't set the state in `onDateChange`

Answer (score 0):

For DatePickerAndroid

> expected dynamic type double

In other words native component wants time, but you put string. You this.props.startDate is string, transfer time in time format. Example:

```
  const {action, year, month, day} = await DatePickerAndroid.open({
    date: new Date() // <- This is Date, not string!
  });
```

Good luck!